# Best Practices: How much inheritance is too much?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Since this is a hypothetical question, I am uncertain whether it belongs here or not. If not, I apologize.

How much should inheritance be relied upon in everyday coding? If I were creating a project where I wanted to have a link from every class to the parent class, should I create a class with a single Parent property, and then inherit all other classes from this one?

I am actually in a situation like this now, where not every class needs a parent link, but enough do that I wonder if I should be using inheritance. I'm also wondering if I should inherit from this class even if I don't use the Parent property, just for consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember what inheritance means:

**Inheritance** means "Is a type of (some other object)"

**Composition** means "Has a (some other object)"

In your case, composition sounds more correct. In the general case, composition is more correct. Only use inheritance in "Is a type of" situations.